# Your Connection is not private just in my websites (privacy Error) - Page Gets Stuck in Security Page

Tags: security, https, connection, secure-gateway, trustedconnection

Chrome gets stuck in security error page: Does not display the *advanced* tab(/button/paragraph) to proceed.

[image: Connection is not Private]

Comment: Use this video, could resolve on my machine - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hb6iD3nP6g&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&index=17

Answer (score 33):

**Attention,**  **Attention**

I have found that the best (and only) way to override Chrome is to type the phrase `thisisunsafe` at the Chrome generate webpage that blocks you.  We have servers on an internal network which use SSL but which are not externally signed and this is the only way to get to them.

enjoy it ;)

Comment: I could not understand where should I write this phrase thisisunsafe at the Chrome

Comment: @baymax, nowhere, it's a hacky solution, just click on the page and try to type ( nothing entered on the page, just click and type without see anything typed on the page)

Comment: This hack really work!

Comment: Only solution that works!

Comment: @pnv glad to hear it helped you ^_^

Comment: im not understand?

Comment: @Netwons just click on the page, everywhere you want on the page, then start typing what I mentioned in the answer. it's a tricky solution

Comment: what a weird way to implement this workaround...

Comment: its working like magic LOL

Answer (score 4):

enter **chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost** in chrome browser

**imp**: change your earlier url eg: if you have used testweb.dev 
change it to testweb.test

now restart the server go to http://testweb.test